# I am trying to use ionic icons in my HTML pages but icons are not displaying

Tags: ionic-framework, icons

I am trying to use ionic icons in my HTML pages. But icons are not displaying.
I am linking `<link src="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" src_type="url" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>` into my page.

And using icon: `<i class="ion-close-round"></i>`
I am very new to programming. So, any help?

Comment: share your code here

Comment: How to share..??

Comment: [go there how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help)

Answer (score 0):

if you use ionic it will works as usage of

```
<ion-icon name="something"></ion-icon>
```

in a list, grid, col, and html tags. First check package.json         `"ionicons": "3.0.0",` is exist or not .. If not please put this value in package.json file.

Comment: If you want to use more icons addition to Ionic Icons you can add font awesome library[link](fontawesome.io/). To install this library in your project [link](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2016/03/use-font-awesome-icons-in-your-ionic-2-android-and-ios-app/ ) document is very useful and simple.

Comment: Thank u.. I'll try

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use more icons addition to Ionic Icons you can add [font awesome library](http://fontawesome.io/). To install this library in your project [document](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2016/03/use-font-awesome-icons-in-your-ionic-2-android-and-ios-app/) is very useful and simple.

Comment: I don't know how this helps the poster with non-displaying icons exactly...

Answer (score 0):

Use below you will get the star icon.

```
<i class = "icon icon ion-star"></i>
```

You can also use star icon in button in the way of

```
<button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-star">Shopping Cart</button>
```

Just try with it.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a similar issue, here is how I got around it:
I went over to the https://github.com/ionic-team/ionicons
 and downloaded the docs folder.

It contains these folders:

- css
- fonts
- Ionicons/svg

I downloaded it and placed it in a folder in the root directory of my development environment.
I now linked the style sheet in the folder I downloaded in my head section

in this case I placed everything I downloaded in the "Ionicons" folder

from now you can use Ionicons anywhere in your page

by using an inline element